# PowerShell Members: explanation for Methods and Properties?

Tags: powershell, methods, properties

I am a newbie when it comes to PowerShell and come from a BASH background from long ago. PowerShell's built-in documentation and help on the web is pretty good, but one area where I keep stumbling is understanding Methods and Properties (are these called members/classes?). I know that I can see which Methods and Properties I can use by doing, as in example:

```
ls | get-member
```

How do `.Exists`, `.Trim`, `.SubString`, or `.Split`, etc. actually work?

Answer (score 8):

When you do `Get-Member`, you will see the TypeName, something like:

```
TypeName: System.IO.DirectoryInfo
```

You can search for that type and look at its members.

These are .NET framework objects and its members and properties, so you can make use of the extensive documentation at msdn.

For example this is the doc for DirectoryInfo: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directoryinfo.aspx

Comment: Agreed, get-member + your favorite search engine is the best solution. Since we're dealing with .NET objects, there is tons of official MSDN/TechNet documentation + lots of samples of people doing similar work in PowerShell or C#.

Comment: Thank you for this, however it doesn't necessarily show me how this should be used in PowerShell. What's the syntax? Is the syntax the same everytime when using methods and are there options ie: `.Method(Get|Set)`? How are Get or Set used and are these the only options?

Comment: Anything with a get;set; is going to be a Property, not a Method. For that you're going to just use dotted notation: get-childitem | foreach-object { $_.length }    ... For actual methods, the syntax is going to look more like a programming language like C# than PowerShell's cmdlets: (get-date).toString("MM-dd-yyyy")

Comment: I guess the part I'm so confused about, how did you know that `("MM-dd-yyyy")` were the parameters to use? If I understand correctly using `.` in the method is like piping the string to that particular method and everything in-between `()` is where the options/parameters are?

Comment: You may want to read this article, which explains the dot operator http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6zhxzbds.aspx  and this article which explains Methods http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173114.aspx  These are both C# topics, but it will help you with understanding their use in PowerShell.

Answer (score 2):

I just posted a script to the scripting repository that may help you with this.  http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Finding-reference-b12324bc

It takes away the effort for you so now you can do something like:

```
Get-ChildItem C:\Windows | Get-Member | .\Find-TypeReference.ps1
```

Which would cause the script to open up the MSDN search page for you with the FileInfo and DirectoryInfo types as the query.

Comment: Just downloaded your script, thanks. As mentioned above, the MSDN site doesn't give me examples on how to use this within PowerShell (however it does give examples from other languages). How do other PowerShell users learn these methods/properties?

Comment: You really do have to do research into learning the .Net Framework to see how to take advantage of these different methods/properties.  As far as learning the syntax for the commands in PowerShell there are a few places you should look.

* get-help new-object -full
* get-help about_Objects
* get-help about_Methods
* get-help about_Properties

Comment: Also, for methods, if you have a string for example { $a = "Testing" } and you pipe that to Get-Member, you will see the definition of methods and properties.  When dealing with methods, you can add the method name without the parenthesis and PowerShell will give you the actual overloaded definitions of how to call the method.  So do something like this to see the different definitions for the substring method: { $a.substring }

Comment: Wow, ok... this is a little closer. With this info and some digging on the net, I'm sure I could figure it out. I just wish there was a central resource for this.